# How to upload a Flink job from WebUI?

Tags: apache-flink

flink cluster version: **flink-1.7.2-bin-scala_2.11**

And it is a docker cluster.

My project structure:

```
--lib  
 +- src/main/scala  
 +- pom.xml  
--job  
 +- src/main/scala    
 +- pom.xml  
pom.xml
```

There are two submodules to this project.

Then I made a fat jar , and upload from web UI.Then I got this Exception:

```
ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.JarRunHandler    - Exception occurred in REST handler: org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error.
```

without the stack trace.

But Running in IDE is OK.

Comment: There should be a stack trace, please post it.

Comment: @孙兴斌 That is what makes me confused. There is no stack trace.I checked out container in $FLINK_HOME/log,and /var/log directory.Only got that by  `docker logs`

Comment: I'm having the same problem running a Docker compose Flink Cluster and submitting a job through the WebUI but only getting `org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error.`  Nothing else.

Comment: It may be the dependencies issues. It works after I change to native cluster and resolve some dependencies issue. So I suppose it's a dependencies issue, especially Kafka's dependencies is a trouble.